# H2 determining if String value is numeric

Tags: sql, jdbc, h2

This is my first time using H2 and I'm trying to select only the records that DO NOT have a numerical ID (e.g. H27384WK would be valid, but 398453 would not). After researching this online, I couldn't find any solutions for this and none of the [functions mentioned here](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#decode) seem to be helpful. How could I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with translate:

```
where translate(id, 'A0123456789', 'A') <> ''
```

You might need to check for `NULL` explicitly (I'm not sure if H2 treats empty strings as NULL the way that Oracle does):

```
where translate(id, 'A0123456789', 'A') is not null
```

Comment: Actually didn't work for me.  Maybe my version of H2 is too old (1.3.x), but it doesn't seem to support translate(...).  The LOWER(...) = UPPER(...) listed below did work.

Answer (score 3):

An other solution is with a combination of UPPER and LOWER

```
WHERE NOT (LOWER(id) = UPPER(id))
```

You might need to add additional conditions for NULL and/or empty values.

Comment: I found it was necessary to add AND id != '' to my where clauses.